# C++: implications in main() of using forward class declarations

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have three C++ classes: Position, Employer and Person.  Each person has an employer and a position in that employment.  As you can see below I have used forward class declarations to join the Employer and Position classes to the Person class.

I am new to forward declaration of classes, but found the [When to use forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869) post to be very insightful with regards to when and how to use forward declaration.

However, I am primarily concerned with how to use setPosition() in my main function?

**person.h**

```
class Position;
class Employer;

class Person
{
public:
    // other public members
    void setPosition(Employer* newC, Position* newP)
    {
        m_position = newP;
        m_employer = newC;
    }
private:
    // other member variables
    Position* m_position;
    Employer* m_employer;
};
```

Here is snippets from **main.cpp**:

```
#include "employer.h"
#include "person.h"
#include "position.h"

int main()
{
    Employer StarFleet("StarFleet Federation", "space exploration");
    Person JLP("Jean-Luc Picard");
    Position cpt("StarFleet Captain", "Save the world");

    JLP.setPosition(StarFleet,cpt);

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is a get a compiling error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Person::setPosition(Employer&, Position&)' in main.cpp
> candidate is:
> void Person::setPosition(Employer*, Position*)
>
> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Employer' to 'Employer*'

I would like to know how you would go about using setPosition in main()?

I hope I have made myself clear.  If you require any more of my code just let me know.

Comment: Would you mind giving me the reason for down-voting my question so that I may improve my question-asking skills for next time? :) Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function arguments are pointers, but you send variables by value. You must use their addresses:

```
JLP.setPosition(&StarFleet,&cpt);
```

Comment: Or change the function to take references.